# How to properly delete AWS ElasticSearch index to free disk space

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-elasticsearch

I am using AWS ElasticSearch, and publishing data to it from AWS Kinesis Firehose delivery stream.

In Kinesis Firehose settings I specified rotation period for ES index as 1 month. Every month Firehose will create new index for me appending month timestamp. As I understand, old index will be still presented, It wouldn’t be deleted.

Questions I have:

1. With new index being created each month with different name, do I need to recreate my Kibana dashboards  each month?
2. Do I need to manually delete old index every month to clean disk space?
3. In order to clean disk space, is it enough just to run CURL command to delete the old index?

Answer (score 1):

> With new index being created each month with different name, do I need to recreate my Kibana dashboards each month?

No, you will need to create an index pattern on kibana, something like `kinesis-*`, then you will create your visualizations and dashboards using this index pattern.

> Do I need to manually delete old index every month to clean disk space?

It depends of which version of Elasticsearch you are using, the last versions have a Index Lifecycle Management built-in in the Kibana UI, if your version does not have it you will need to do it manually or use `curator`, an elasticsearch python application to deal with theses tasks.

> In order to clean disk space, is it enough just to run CURL command to delete the old index?

Yes, if you delete an index it will free the space used by that index.